# Apache commons parser to read a CSV file with BOM

Tags: csv, file, parsing, apache-commons

i got something like that..

```
final CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.RFC4180.builder()
.setHeader()
.setSkipHeaderRecord(true)
.setIgnoreHeaderCase(true)
.setDelimiter('|')
.build();

if (Files.isRegularFile(myPath)) {

  try (
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myPath.toFile()));
    final CSVParser parser = csvFormat.parse(reader);) {

      for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
          String issuer = csvRecord.get("MY_COLUMN_NAME");
          //some code
      }
  }
```

All is perfect whe i read some files with no BOM,
but not when i wanna read some BOM files.
I got an error, like :

```
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping for "MY_COLUMN_NAME" not found, expected one of..
```

In fact, when MY_COLUMN_NAME is the first column of the file, and file with BOM, the Apache parser doesn't wanna read the file.

Does everybody has an idea ?